# "(too old to migrate)" shouldn't show on Meta Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, close-dialog, migration

When voting to close an old question on Meta, the close dialog is presented:

[image]

However there is no option to migrate from Meta:

[image]

The *(too old to migrate)* text should be removed.

Comment: I thought the first option was the migration path to Stack Overflow. Isn't it?

Comment: @bfavaretto: No.  That option just closes the question.  There is no migration path to Stack Overflow; most people who post programming questions on Meta do it to try and circumvent a question ban on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @bfavaretto No, the option to get to the [migration-dialog] looks like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/WC6W4.png The [migration-dialog] itself looks like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CN342.png

Comment: Ah, I see. @RobertHarvey I never realized that! They think they're being smart, but they have no clue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with the next build, the "(too old to migrate)" message won't show if there are no migration targets on a site.

Comment: tool? did you mean too?

Comment: @FDinoff oops, fixed!